# Why sudo pm-suspend does not work in i3 tiling window manager?

Tags: bash

I have a little problem with the i3 tiling window manager's ~/.i3/config file.
I am trying to set the pm-suspend utility as a key-binding of Mod4 (the windows key) + p (the p char).

I have this bash script called **suspendandlock** in **/usr/bin/**:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pm-suspend | i3lock -i /home/antony/unity-desk.png -p default -d -n
```

I previously modified the /etc/sudoers file with visudo, adding this line:

```
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

So that no one needs the password to execute pm-suspend utility.

Then I have my i3 config file, where I added this:

```
bindsym $mod+p exec suspendandlock
```

Where $mod is the Mod4 key.
The script works fine from gnome-terminal when I type the suspendandlock command -> it suspends the system and blocks the screen as expected.

But when I type Mod4+p from keyboard it only blocks the screen without executing pm-suspend.
Why does it not work?

Does anyone knows where I am wrong?

Comment: I resolved, my user was not in the users group.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like OP solved the problem, but for anyone else who needed to fix it (myself included), just run:

```
sudo usermod -aG users `whoami`
which pm-suspend || sudo apt-get install pm-utils #make sure you have pm-suspend command, install it if you don't
```

run `sudo visudo` and add:

```
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

and then add:

```
bindsym $mod+p exec "sudo pm-suspend | i3lock"
```

to ~/.i3/config. Running $mod+p will now lock and then suspend your computer.

Comment: make sure you logout and back in for group modification to take effect.